# Powershell SMTP report with attachment issues needs corrections

Tags: email, powershell, automation

I created this tiny script to full fill a repeated request from audit. I want to expand it but ran into an issue with file creation.

This code will create the `$attachment` in the directory it is run from. When using ISE it stores the `$attachment` to the `system32` folder. When run from the script repository it leaves the file in the same directory. The goal is for the file to be attached and emailed out not leaving any remnants behind. This script is used in many functions for auditing so I will be using this as a "standard" process for automating audit reports. I am very new to scripting but looking for all feedback!!

Eventually there will be multiple attachments to be added and this run weekly. Right now they are all individual scripts that are run as requested.

```
    #Run Cleanup for ISE Variables using Preloaded Profile
#Cleanup 
#Mailsettings
$SmtpSender = "Email@mail.com"
$SmtpReceiver = "User@mail.com"
$SmtpSubject = "User accounts enabled-Auditonly"
$SmtpBody = "Attached is run from PDQ using script Users.enabled-Auditonly.ps1"
$Smtpservr = "smtp.mail.com"
#Variables
$attachment = New-Item "Users.enabled-Auditonly$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss')).csv" -ItemType File


Get-ADuser -Filter * -Properties Name, SamAccountName,Description, Enabled | Select Name, SamAccountName,Description, Enabled |
export-csv $attachment
#Grabs the attachment from the above location and emails it out.
Send-MailMessage -Attachments $attachment -Body $SmtpBody -BodyAsHtml -From $SmtpSender -To $SmtpReceiver -Subject $SmtpSubject -SmtpServer $Smtpservr
```

Comment: The [`-Attachments`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Send-MailMessage) parameter allows specifying _the **path and file names** of files to be attached to the email message_.  For instance, `$attachment = New-Item "$env:temp\Users.enabled-Auditonl…` could help?

Comment: set your $attachment variable to just the file (path and) name: `$attachment = "Users.enabled-Auditonly$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss')).csv"`. It will be created by the `Export-Csv` cmdlet (where BTW I would add switch `-NoTYpeInformation`. You don't want to use `New-Item`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible I try to avoid creating temp files during script execution because they tend to introduce side effects and bugs related to security, permission, cleanup and duplicates.

`Export-Csv` creates a file but [ConvertTo-Csv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-7.1) creates a string variable, which will allow you to avoid an intermediate file.

The `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet you're using takes attachments that rely on a local path, but the .Net object `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` allows adding attachments from an in-memory string. There's a good example of its use on [send-mailmessage-attachment-from-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049923/send-mailmessage-attachment-from-memory).
Instead of `$([System.Net.Mail.Attachment]::CreateAttachmentFromString("HELLO2", "Test2.txt"))` you can use this:

```
$AttachmentName = "Users.enabled-Auditonly$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss')).csv"
$AttachmentContents = Get-ADuser -Filter * -Properties Name, SamAccountName,Description, Enabled | Select Name, SamAccountName,Description, Enabled | ConvertTo-Csv 

$MailAttachment = [System.Net.Mail.Attachment]::CreateAttachmentFromString($AttachmentContents,$AttachmentName)
```

... and pass that `$MailAttachment` object to the function.